# Nginx redirection to https://www.domain.tld

Tags: redirect, nginx, configuration, https, subdomain

I am trying to make my domain name only work with a https:// and www in front of it. It's important that domain.com without the www. redirects to the www, and it's also important that https:// is always enabled. I am having a lot of trouble achieving this. I've removed all the redirects from the config because they all just give me errors.

```
    server {
    listen   80;
    default_type text/html; 
    server_name epicmc.us;

    location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
    }


    server {
    listen 443;
    default_type text/html;
    server_name www.epicmc.us;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 5s;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-EXP:!kEDH:!aNULL;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;

    location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    # proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    # root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    # # With php5-cgi alone:
    # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    # deny all;
    #}
    }
    }
```

EDIT: I am now using a PHP redirect, but there has to be a better option...

Answer (score 0):

You should define additional virtualhost, and there redirect all clients to desired method+host.

Add to your config (tune to your taste, of course) :

```
# redirection vhost
server {
    listen      10.1.2.3:80;
    server_name www.epicmc.us epicmc.us;
    access_log  /logs/access.log  full;
    error_log   /logs/error.log  notice;
    location / {
        rewrite  ^/(.*)$  https://www.epicmc.us/$1  permanent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this, simple redirect **return 301**

```
    server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    listen         80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

or using **rewrite** rules, check the answer for this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom) it might be helpful

```
 server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com ;
        location{
             rewrite ^(.*)$   https://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
         }
}
```

check answers for this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom) it might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I'm using Cloudflare's flexible SSL, so my problem was that I had to do the page rules on their site and not in my config. That's why I was getting redirect errors.